# Best Practice to call different lists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Now I'm calling object into _Layout menu with `PartialView` like these:

Controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetChemicalsList()
{
    var model = db.ProductsList.Where(x => x.Subcategory.Name == "Chemicals").ToList();
    return PartialView(@"~/Views/Product/_ChemicalPartialView.cshtml", model);
}
```

Partial View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Product>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Product", new { id= item.ProductId})">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</a>
}
```

Layout View:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2">
    @Html.Action("GetChemicalsList", "Product")
</div>
```

But I have another products with different subcategory to add, so I need to do a controller and different call into View for each one because each one have a different query on controller: for example, I  do another one for accessories, so my controller be like these one:

Accessories controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetAccesoriesList()
{
    var model = db.ProductsList.Where(x => x.Subcategory.Name == "Accesories").ToList(); // diferent Query
    return PartialView(@"~/Views/Product/_ChemicalPartialView.cshtml", model);
}
```

_Layout View

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2">
   @Html.Action("GetAccesoriesList", "Product")
</div>
```

Is the correct way to do that, or there another best way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can just have one method with a parameter for the `Subcategory.Name` say `public async Task<ActionResult> Fetch(string category)` and use `@Html.Action("Fetch", Product", new { category = "Accesories")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a generic Action that will return your list depending on what sub category you want. Then you pass it from the view to controller as route data.

**Controller:**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetSubCategoryList(string subCategory)
{
    var model = db.ProductsList.Where(x => x.Subcategory.Name == subCategory).ToList(); 
    return PartialView(@"~/Views/Product/_ChemicalPartialView.cshtml", model);
}
```

**View:**

```
@Html.Action("GetSubCategoryList", "Product", new { subCategory = "Accessories" })
```

You may need to change your route config to match this route.